# What's the best way to calculate a daily cumulative sum?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, cumsum

I found a way to get the number I need, but I was hoping to get some input on how to accomplish it in a less cumbersome way. I need a running total of transactions to date in order to make it into a plotly plot. The data I have only includes a few columns: id, date, and amount. Here's the code I have so far:

```
fy20 = pd.read_excel('./data/transactions.xlsx', parse_dates=['date'])
def daily_money(df):
    df = df.groupby('date').amount.sum()
    df = df.groupby(df.index.day).cumsum()
    df = df.cumsum().to_frame().reset_index()
    return df

fy20 = daily_money(fy20)
```

This appears to accomplish the goal, but it seems like there must be a simpler way. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to simplify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like this should work:

```
df.groupby('date')['amount'].sum().cumsum()
```

This works because [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) automatically sorts by the group keys, so the cumulative sum is already looking at the data it needs.

If you want it as a DataFrame with a new index instead of a Series, you can just use [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), which converts the series to a DataFrame first, but unless you need the date as a normal column (rather than the index) later, you don't need to do that.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks so much for your help with that one. I really appreciated the tip about using `reset_index` on a Series. A lot of my plotting methods used DataFrame properties as opposed to Series and it saved me some work.